# cannot initialize type decimal with a collection initializer error in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to initialize a multidimensional array in csharp. I am getting error cannot initialize type decimal with a collection initializer because it does not implement systems.collections.IEnumerable. Not sure what the 
 problem is

Json structure

```
 "StressTestAnalysis": {
    "GraphData": [
      [ 90000, 1, 1000000],
      [ 91000, 1, 2000000],
      [ 92000, 1, 3000000],
      [ 93000, 1, 4000000],
      [ 94000, 1, 5000000],
      [ 95000, 1, 6000000],
      [ 96000, 1, 7000000],
      [ 97000, 1, 8000000],
      [ 98000, 1, 9000000],
      [ 99000, 0, 10000000],
      [ 100000, 0, 11000000],
      [ 101000, 0, 12000000],
      [ 102000, 0, 13000000],
      [ 103000, 0, 14000000],
      [ 104000, 0, 15000000],
      [ 105000, 0, 16000000],
      [ 106000, 0, 17000000],
      [ 107000, 0, 18000000],
      [ 108000, 0, 19000000],
      [ 109000.00000000001, 0, 20000000],
      [ 110000.00000000001, 0, 21000000]
    ],




 public class StressTestAnalysis
    {
        public StressTestResults Results { get; set; }
        public decimal[][][] GraphData { get; set; }
    }


       trigger2Output.StressTestAnalysis.GraphData = new decimal[][][]
            {
               new decimal { 90000, 1, 1000000}

            } ;
```

Comment: `public decimal[][] GraphData` ?

Comment: Your class is wrong, you don't need a three dimensional array.

Comment: Then is it two dimensional

Comment: Even if i make it two dimensional i have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is wrong, you don't need a three dimensional array. You only need 2 dimensions. Also the collection initialiser code needs a small tweak:

The updated class:

```
public class StressTestAnalysis
{
    public StressTestResults Results { get; set; }
    public decimal[][] GraphData { get; set; }
}
```

And code to fill it:

```
//Note this is now a 2D array
trigger2Output.StressTestAnalysis.GraphData = new decimal[][]
{
    new decimal[] { 90000, 1, 1000000}
    //         ^^ add this
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up how many dimensions you want in your array(s).  For starters, this:

```
new decimal { 90000, 1, 1000000}
```

You're declaring a single `decimal`, but trying to initalize it as an array.  Declare it as an array:

```
new decimal[] { 90000, 1, 1000000}
```

Then, one level higher, you're using that as an element in another array:

```
new decimal[][][]
{
   new decimal[] { 90000, 1, 1000000}
}
```

But your array contains one array, not an array of arrays.  This makes it *two* dimensions, not *three*:

```
new decimal[][]
{
   new decimal[] { 90000, 1, 1000000}
}
```

Update your class property to account for this:

```
public decimal[][] GraphData { get; set; }
```

And you can now successfully set your *two*-dimensional array.